# Cuda - printing string from object in __global__ function

Tags: string, cuda, global, host

I am new to CUDA and I am getting a strange error. I want to print a string from a passed object and I get the error "calling host function from global function is not allowed" and I don't know why. But if I want to print an integer (changing get method to return sk1), everything works fine. Here is the code:

```
class Duomenys {   
private:
   string simb;
   int sk1;
   double sk2;
 public:
      __device__ __host__ Duomenys(void): simb(""), sk1(0), sk2(0.0) {}
      __device__ __host__~Duomenys() {} 

    __device__ __host__ Duomenys::Duomenys(string simb1, int sk11, double sk21)
              : simb(simb1), sk1(sk11), sk2(sk21) {}

    __device__ __host__ string Duomenys::get(){
        return simb;
    }
};
```

And here I am calling Duomenys::get from __global__ function:

```
__global__ void Vec_add(Duomenys a) {   
     printf(" %s \n",a.get());
}
```

**EDIT:** I am trying to read data from a file and print it in a global function. In this code I am trying read all data and print just one object to see if everything works. This is the error I'm getting:

```
 calling a __host__ function("std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string") from a __global__ function("Vec_add") is not allowed
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <vector>  
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Duomenys {   
private:
   string simb;
   int sk1;
   double sk2;
 public:
      __device__ __host__ Duomenys(void): simb(""), sk1(0), sk2(0.0) {}
      __device__ __host__~Duomenys() {} 

    __device__ __host__ Duomenys::Duomenys(string simb1, int sk11, double sk21)
              : simb(simb1), sk1(sk11), sk2(sk21) {}

    __device__ __host__ string Duomenys::print()
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << left << setw(10) << simb << setw(10) << sk1 << setw(10) << sk2;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

__global__ void Vec_add(Duomenys a) {

     printf(" %s \n",a.print());
}  


/* Host code */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   setlocale (LC_ALL,"");
    vector<Duomenys> vienas;
    vector<vector<Duomenys>> visi;

    //data reading to vector "vienas" (it works without any errors)

    Duomenys *darr;
    const size_t sz = size_t(2) * sizeof(Duomenys);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&darr, sz);
     Vec_add<<<1, 1>>>(visi[0].at(0));
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     cudaMemcpy(darr, &visi[0].at(0), sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `printf` from within a `__global__` function is only allowed for cards with compute capability >= `2.0`.

Comment: I know, with printf everything is working perfect ( i can use printf("%s", "text") without any problem), but when I want to print string from object I am getting errors. That's the problem.

Comment: Is `a` a host or device object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we use the string data type in C++ within kernels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910739/can-we-use-the-string-data-type-in-c-within-kernels)

Comment: The error is coming from std::string.get() being called in the kernel, not printf.

Comment: I know. I need the answer how to print, not where error is..
p.s. I edited my question and added more code. Take a look if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you pass a `string` object to `printf` when the `%s` format specifier is [expecting something else](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)?   When I try to do that in ordinary host code, I get warnings about "passing non-POD types through ellipsis (call will abort at runtime)".  Note that this problem has *nothing to do with CUDA*.

But beyond that issue, presumably you're getting `string` from the C++ standard library.  (It's better if you show a complete reproducer code, then I don't have to guess at where you're getting things or what you are including.)

If I get `string` as follows:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Then I am using a function defined in the C++ Standard Library.  CUDA supports the C++ *language* (mostly) but does not necessarily support usage of C++ libraries (or C libraries, for that matter) in device code.  Libraries are (usually) composed of (at least some) compiled code (such as allocators, in this case), and this code has been compiled for CPUs, not for the GPU.  When you try to use such a CPU compiled routine (e.g. an allocator associated with the `string` class) in device code, the compiler will bark at you.  If you include the complete error message in the question, it will be more obvious specifically what (compiled-for-the-host) function is actually the issue.

Use a standard C style string instead (i.e. `char[]` and you will be able to use it directly in `printf`.

**EDIT**: In response to a question in the comments, here is a modified version of the code posted that demonstrates how to use an ordinary C-style string (i.e. `char[]`) and print from it in device code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define STRSZ 32
using namespace std;

class Duomenys {
private:
   char simb[STRSZ];
   int sk1;
   double sk2;
 public:
      __device__ __host__ Duomenys(void):  sk1(0), sk2(0.0) {}
      __device__ __host__~Duomenys() {}

    __device__ __host__ Duomenys(char  *simb1, int sk11, double sk21)
              :  sk1(sk11), sk2(sk21) {}

    __device__ __host__ char * print()
    {
        return simb;
    }
    __device__ __host__ void store_str(const char *str)
    {
    for (int i=0; i< STRSZ; i++)
      simb[i] = str[i];
    }
};

__global__ void Vec_add(Duomenys a) {

     printf(" %s \n",a.print());
}


/* Host code */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string host_string("hello\n");
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"");
    vector<Duomenys> vienas(3);
    vienas[0].store_str(host_string.c_str());
    vector<vector<Duomenys> > visi(3);
    visi[0] = vienas;

    //data reading to vector "vienas" (it works without any errors)

    Duomenys *darr;
    const size_t sz = size_t(2) * sizeof(Duomenys);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&darr, sz);
    Vec_add<<<1, 1>>>(visi[0].at(0));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(darr, &(visi[0].at(0)), sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I didn't try to understand your code or fix everything that looked strange to me.  However this should demonstrate one possible approach.

Comment: I edited my question and added more code. Take a look if you can.

P.s. - I tried to convert string in object to C-string with `c_str()`, but I just getting back empty string.

Comment: I tried to convert with `strcpy(chr, simb.c_str());`, and now printf doesnt call error, but always prints `null`

Comment: I've already explained this.  `c_str()` or `.str()` are coming from a C++ library which you *cannot use in device code*.  When you call `.print()` in device code, it wants to call `.str()` and it cannot use that function.  Use a standard C style string instead.

Comment: When I compile the code you have currently posted, I get all the usual warning messages I referred to previously.  You haven't fixed any of the compile issues.

Comment: get rid of the string class and the `#include <string>` in your code.  You can use the elements of that library in host code but not device code.  `string` `.c_str()` `.str()` and `strcpy()` all come from `string`.  You cannot use or call any of that from device code.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But how I should do if I want to read `string` from file in host and print it in `global` function? I don't understand

Comment: I edited my answer (again) with a complete, compilable example demonstrating how to use a C-style string in a class and print from it in device code.  I edited it again slightly to use <string> on the host side only.  Be sure to compile with -arch=sm_20 or similar to enable printf from device code.

Comment: And one more question - it is possible somehow copy array of `Duomenys` to kernel nad print it?

Comment: Yes, you can copy an array of objects to the device.  Since your `Duomenys` class has no dynamically allocated data, it's pretty easy.  Search on "cuda copy object to device" (or something like that) in the upper right hand corner search box on this page to get some ideas, or else post a new SO question.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not with printf function, but with string data type. You cannot use the C++ string type in a kernel. See related question here: [Can we use the string data type in C++ within kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910739/can-we-use-the-string-data-type-in-c-within-kernels)